# Bluetooth to Android to Arduino communication: Is It possible?

Tags: android, bluetooth, arduino, arduino-uno, robotics

I have mostly a general question, so I'm sorry if this is too broad. But I am working on plan for a robot and I wanna connect devices together.

Basically, I want to have an Android device connect to an Arduino Uno via Bluetooth, and then the Android Device connect to either another Android, or to a Bluetooth controller. The reason for this is that I want the main Android device to be used as a controller, and feed instructions to the Android device connected to the arduino, and that device to the arduino, and carry out that instruction. But is that even possible? If not, how can I work around it? And if it is possible, any examples?

Summary:
*Android Device to Android Device to Arduino via Bluetooth 
*First device as a controller, second as a brain to arduino
*First communicates with second, second communicates with arduino

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yepp bro it's possible i did with some other development board other than arduino
but the important thing is concept and it's same for all developement boards.
In my project i created a connection between an android mobile & robot and then controlled its movement through an App like picking up an object using robotic arm and its motion.

Comment: Thanks! Now that it is possible by what you said, I can make my jumping robot :)